# When were the Peverell and Slytherin families joined?

Tags: harry-potter, voldemort, slytherin, genealogy

Voldemort was a descendant of Salazar Slytherin and Cadmus Peverell.
Is there any source stating when the two families joined?

Comment: We couldn't find it in a previous discussion, but it's been a few weeks and Rowling appears to randomly generate HP canon.  It had to be sometime after 1214 AD.

Comment: @Axelrod it was clear, that there was an upper bound, but is there also a lower bound, which is before Marvolo Gaunt is born or proofs that he was the first descendant of both families?

Comment: There's a lower bound of Corvinus Gaunt, who was a descendant of both houses and defended the location of the Chamber of Secrets in the 1700s. That's from Pottermore. So between ~1200 and ~1700.

Comment: @Axelrod if you make an answer out of it (with the source) I can mark it as answer, because this would be the correct answer

Comment: this question is not a duplicate, since this is not about whether they are related, but since when this joined line existed. and the answer in the marked question doesn't even address this point...

Answer (score 11, accepted):

### We aren't sure of the exact date or descendant, but we have upper and lower bounds; it was somewhere between the 13th and 18th centuries.

As [Cadmus Peverell](http://harrypotter.wikia.com/wiki/Cadmus_Peverell) lived in 1214, we can say for sure that the two families were not united before that time, despite [Salazar Slytherin](http://harrypotter.wikia.com/wiki/Salazar_Slytherin) being alive in the 10th century.

As [Corvinus Gaunt](http://harrypotter.wikia.com/wiki/Corvinus_Gaunt) is the descendant of both houses and was said in Pottermore to [have defended the location of the Chamber of Secrets](https://www.pottermore.com/writing-by-jk-rowling/chamber-of-secrets) when Hogwarts first had plumbing installed, we can definitely say that the families were united by his lifetime.

As such, that leaves us with a range from the 13th through 18th centuries.  This is a large space of time, but it's still the best answer we currently have.

[image: Gaunt]